# MVC Package load (NuGet)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

After installing the package with NuGet console (called [bootstrap-table](https://github.com/simonray/bootstrap-table.mvc)), in packages.config I can see that the package is added but I cannot use it, nor the htmlhelpers that are coming with it.

I tried reinstalling the package, restarting VS2013 but it doesn't seem to help.

When I run the sample project from Simonray I can see the htmlhelpers, but his project doesn't use the package but a precompilled dll.
Here is a screenshot from NuGet package manager, his and mine projects: http://prntscr.com/75gjar

Any advice?

Comment: Why did you tag this as two different versions of MVC? Where's your code? What exception are you getting?

Comment: I dont get any exception, I cannot use the html helpers from the package. It contains Html.Bootstraptable but VS doesnt recognize the function, i reinstalled the package, checked the package.config file and still cant use it

Comment: Just write the code, then try to compile. See if VS gives you a compilation exception. And **update your question to show your code**.

Answer (score 0):

In the `web.config` in your `Views` folder, you need to add the namespace. This is equivalent to adding a `using` statement in C#, add this last line:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      ...
      <add namespace="BootstrapTable.Web" />
```

Note that the example project you linked already has this line included [here](https://github.com/simonray/bootstrap-table.mvc/blob/master/BootstrapTable.Web/Views/Web.config).

Comment: It doesnt show the bootstrap-table in the references for some reason, i tried it adding manually, now i am able to get intellisense when adding namespace in web.config in views (http://prntscr.com/75gyu5) but I get this compilation error when i run it: http://prntscr.com/75gz1b

Comment: Maybe because the folder says .net 4.5.2 and im on .net 4.5.1 and that is why NuGet doesnt add it into references? When i try to install the package it says: 'bootstrap-table.mvc 1.1.1' already installed.
oXFakturiranje already has a reference to 'bootstrap-table.mvc 1.1.1'.

Comment: Perhaps the Nuget package isn't adding a project reference then, can you check that BootstrapTable is listed in the references and if not, add it in?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got it to work. It would seem that the latest version of the package is slightly borked.

1) Firstly, install version 1.0.0 of the package into the project using the following command:

```
Install-Package bootstrap-table.mvc -Version 1.0.0
```

This correctly adds the reference to the `BootstrapTable` dll.

2) Now, run the `Update-Package` command like so:

```
Update-Package bootstrap-table.mvc
```

3) Updating the package unfortunately for some reason removes the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` package. Sigh. So you should now re-add it by using the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
```

4) Build your project.

5) The Html helpers for `BootstrapTable` are in the namespace `System.Web.Mvc`. This namespace should already be in the `Web.config` that is in the `Views` folder... but if not you should add it:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    ...
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        ...
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

6) Everything should now work.